# How to specify a group when displaying an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController

Tags: iphone, contacts, addressbook, peoplepicker

How do you specify a group when initially displaying an `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` (so it doesn't automatically display "All Contacts")?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I do. I had to make it work.

Set your class as the delegate of the people picker (pp.delegate = self;)

Then implement:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([navigationController.viewControllers count] > 1) {
        navigationController.delegate = nil;
        [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```

It seems to work best with animation off, but still works with it on but sort of goofy. Only tested on simulator.

D