# How to specify a group when displaying an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController?

Tags: xcode, abpeoplepickerview

This question seems to be answered by 50% only:
[How to specify a group when displaying an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434334/how-to-specify-a-group-when-displaying-an-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller)

After the contacts will be displayed, all contact groups will be displayed.

I want to display all contacts for special group.

Is that possible?

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this solution doesn't work anymore with xCode 4.6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434334/how-to-specify-a-group-when-displaying-an-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller , Are there other ideas how to display the contacts for the special group? Thanks!

Comment: Any ideas about this ABPeoplePickerNavigationController issue?